# Facebook bug with Add to My Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I have around 200 tabs and pages linked to my Facebook account.

Recently Facebook have updated the popup on an application profile page (after clicking "Add to My Page") to only load a few pages at a time with a "See More" button at the bottom.

Only problem is this doesn't work! Clicking just gives an error "Something's gone wrong. We're working to get it fixed as soon as we can."

Which isn't much help, as I can't add new tabs to a page that starts with anything after "L".

Is anyone else experiencing this problem or found a way around it?

Comment: I've also found a quicker solution than using the API:

<script>
        top.location = 'http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=YOUR_APP_ID&pages=1';   
</script>

Running this script through an app allows you to pick from existing pages. Hope this helps someone until FB fix.

Answer (score 0):

There's an open bug report about this currently - you can use the API as a workaround https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        top.location = 'http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=YOUR_APP_ID&pages=1';   
</script>
```

Running this code through an app is also a quicker solution than using the API - hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

You can execute this following link in your browser:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id={your_app_id}&display=popup&next={url_of_your_page}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try going to http://www.addpagetab.com/ So much easier and you don't have to reference your code string every single time.